# how to give dtStart and until for Recurring event using angular bootstrap calendar?

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs, spring-mvc

In angular js service file I am using RRULE.WEEKLY here I want to give dtStart and until dynamically with multiple events

```
 $scope.$watchGroup([
                $scope.calendarView,
                angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
                    if(value.recursOn === 'week'){
                        $scope.viewDate = value.startDate,
                        $scope.viewEndDate = value.endDate
                    }
                }),
            ], function() {

          // Use the rrule library to generate recurring events: https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule
          var rule = new RRule({
            freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
            interval: 1,
            byweekday: [RRule.MO],
            dtstart: moment($scope.viewDate).toDate(),
            until: moment($scope.viewEndDate).toDate()
          });

          angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
                    if(value.recursOn !== 'week'){
                    $scope.schedules.push(value);
                }

                });

          rule.all().forEach(function(date) {
            angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
                    if(value.recursOn === 'week'){
                    $scope.schedules.push({
                matchDesc: value.matchDesc,
                teamName: value.teamName,
                color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.success,
                startDate: new Date(date)
            });
                }

                });
          });

        });
```

In this I am trying to get multiple events with Recurring weekly, So for this I am using angular for each to get events from database but how to set multiple events start date and end date to dtStart and until.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you have do like this.

```
var rule = {};
       $scope.$watchGroup([
                $scope.calendarView,

            ], function() {
       angular.forEach(data, function (value, index) {
       // Use the rrule library to generate recurring events:https://github.com/jkbrzt/rrule

       if(value.recursOn === 'week'){
              rule = new RRule({
               freq: RRule.WEEKLY,
               interval: 1,
               byweekday: [RRule.MO],
               dtstart: moment(value.startDate).toDate(),
               until: moment(value.endDate).toDate()
             });
          }

       rule.all().forEach(function(date) {

                if(value.recursOn === 'week'){
              $scope.schedules.push({
                    matchDesc: value.matchDesc,
                    teamName: value.teamName,
                    color: calendarConfig.colorTypes.success,
                    startDate: new Date(date)
               });
              }
          });   
         });


    });
```

It's working for Recurring event weekly using RRULE.WEEKLY with dtstart and until dynamically to no of events.

Hope it would help.